# Is the the number of generators of a group the number of different generators that one finds if one counts over every generating set of the group?

Tags: group-theory

Consider the additive group of integers as an example as mentioned at the bottom of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group). There are two generating sets that are mentioned; The set consisting of the number 1, {1}, and the two-element set, {3,5}. So when we talk about the number of generators of a group do we mean the number of different elements within every generating set, all added together. So above we've counted 3 generators so far, 1,3, and 5 - although there is clearly more than this in total since we haven't mentioned all the generating sets of the group.

As another example, in SU(N) we have $N^{2}-1$ generators. Would this be the total number of generating matrices that we'd get if we counted every single generating set?

On a similar note, would we only count a generator once if it appeared in more than one generating set? So for example if some group had generating sets {1,5}, {5,9}, {3,4,12}, would we say this group had 6 generators, rather than 7?

Comment: The title of this question is like a tongue-twister, but worse: I can repeat it but not understand it.

Comment: Haha, well my apologies. I'll try and reword it.

Comment: I still am not sure what the question is, but when we talk of "the number of generators of a group" we *usually* mean the **minimal** number of generators necessary to generate the whole group, otherwise it'd be explicitly said. Thus, the (*minimal*) number of generators of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is one, never matters that we can find sets with two, three or more elements that also generate $\,\Bbb Z\,$...

Comment: I thought the minimal number of generators that combine to form a group is the rank of the group.

Also, I hope the title is now clearer.

Comment: That is *one* definition of "rank of group". there are several one, depending on the context. About the title...*sigh*...well, let's try: if you take all the possible generators sets of, say the cyclic group of order $\,5\,,\,C_5:=\langle c\rangle\,$, you get **all** the possible subsets of the set $\,C_5\,$ *except* the empty set and $\,\{1\}\,$ , so...what'd be the number of generators *in this case* for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group $G$ typically have many different generating sets, that is subsets $S\subseteq G$ with $\langle S\rangle = G$, and among these are sets of different cardinality (for example, trivially $S=G$ is a generating set).
Therefore it makes little sense to speak of *the* number of generators of a group (or even of *the* set of generators).

We do speak of the free group $F_S$ generated by the set $S$ and for such a free group, the set $S$ is a *canonical* choice of generators. Nevertheless, the free group over $S=\{a,b\}$ is also generated by $\{a,b,1,a^{-2},bab\}$.
In general, when we speak of a group generated by $n$ elements, we mean a group $G$ that allows an epimorphism $f\colon F_S\to G$ where $|S|=n$, typically given by a *presentation* $G=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\mid\ldots\rangle$. Depending on the author, it may additionally be understood that $f|_S$ is injective, that is that the generators of $G$ obtained this may are actually an $n$-element set. But I guess it is often not the case that this distinction is made.

In summary, "a group generated by $n$ elements" should usually be more precisely called "a group that has at least one generating set of at most $n$ elements".
For example, a *cyclic* group is a group generated by a single element. We do however also count the trivial group as cyclic, even though it can in fact be generated by zero elements.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and helpful response. So when we say SU(N) has $N^{2} -1$ generators we're counting generators from a very specific generating set of SU(N)? Also, when we say it has rank $N-1$, do we mean the generating set of the smallest cardinality has $N-1$ generators?